# Python Regex to detect musical chords? (modified)

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on a chord transposer in Python, and have most things working, but there's a couple of problems with my regex, and I was wondering if someone more wise in the ways of regex than I might have an idea of how to fix. I'm essentially using this regex, found in another thread:

```
import re

def findChords(line):
    notes = "[CDEFGAB]";
    accidentals = "(?:#|##|b|bb)?";
    chords = "(?:maj|min|m|sus|aug|dim)?";
    additions = "[0-9]?"
    return re.findall(notes + accidentals + chords + additions, line)

# Case 1, which works:
line = "A    A7    Am7    Bb   Cmaj7"
print findChords(line)
['A', 'A7', 'Am7', 'Bb', 'Cmaj7']

# Case 2, which thinks the capital C in chorus is a chord.
line = "Chorus: A    A7    Am7    Bb   Cmaj7"
print findChords(line)
['C', 'A', 'A7', 'Am7', 'Bb', 'Cmaj7']
```

As you can see, "case 1" above works just fine. However, "case 2" fails, thinking the capital C in the word "Chorus" is a chord.

Can anything think of a way to modify the "notes" part of the regex so its smart enough to make this kind of omission? It should also omit things like the "B" in "Baseball", etc.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Add `r'\b'` to the start of the regex and `r'(?!\w)'` to the end, making it so that the regex can only match against something that's a complete word (where a "word" is a sequence of alphanumeric characters and/or underscores):

```
def findChords(line):
    notes = "[CDEFGAB]";
    accidentals = "(?:#|##|b|bb)?";
    chords = "(?:maj|min|m|sus|aug|dim)?";
    additions = "[0-9]?"
    return re.findall(r'\b' + notes + accidentals + chords + additions + r'(?!\w)', line)
```

(Note that we can't use `r'\b'` at the end because then a chord ending with `#` would never be accepted.)